# Serilog's Splunk Sink (installed from NuGet) shows SSL connection could not be established error

Tags: .net-core, serilog

I created a .NET core 3.1 console application. Installed Serilog and Serilog's Splunk sink packages. My coding is as below:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .WriteTo.Console()
                    .WriteTo.File("logs/myapp.txt", rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day)
                    .WriteTo.EventCollector("Host/services/collector", "Token", source: Environment.MachineName, sourceType: "mySourceType", host: "myHost", index: "my_index")
                    .CreateLogger();
```

I see below error when I send logs:

> ```
> 2022-02-24T08:44:40.6160913Z Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.Splunk.EventCollectorSink:
> ```
>
> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be
> established, see inner exception.
> ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Is there a way to disable certificate validation while using NuGet packages as suggested in other queries?

Comment: Have you tried using an http collector endpoint instead of https?